# HTML Marquee between 2 divs?

Tags: html

I've got a website with images tot he left and right in their own divs, one with float:right and one with float:left.
I also have an image that travels across the screen with the marquee tag.
Is there any way to get the marquee between the divs? So basically it would start at the left side of the right images and start to disappear on the right side of the left images.
If you don't get what I'm on about, here's an example page: http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Example.html and as you can see, the marquee just appears underneath both divs, even when there's enough space for the marqueeing image between the divs.

This is my code for the test site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float:left; width:350px">
<img src="Jaffa.png">
<img src="Jaffa.png">
<img src="Jaffa.png">
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:350px" >
<img src="Jaffa.png">
<img src="Jaffa.png">
<img src="Jaffa.png">
</div>
<p style="text-align: center">
<marquee><img src="Hobnobs.jpg"></marquee>
</p>
```

Can anybody help? I really don't know how to sort it out, I've tried putting the marquee in a div in the centre but it didn't work either.

Comment: Marquees are dead long back. What you wanna really achieve?

Comment: **What you wanna really achieve?**

Comment: I want a cool sliding hobnob

Comment: Some light reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @Ambidextroid: That quote is going on my headstone when I die.

Answer (score 0):

you can use position:absolute as I did:

```
.left,.right,.center{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.left,.right{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:orange;
}
.center{
    left:200px;
    right:200px;
}
.left{
    left:0;
}
.right{
    right:0;
}

<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="center">
    <marquee>
        <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png" alt="">
    </marquee>
</div>
```

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/78pgca5o/

Answer (score 0):

Just give a style as float:left to paragraph tag
Just like below

```
<p style="text-align: center;float:left">
<marquee><img src="Hobnobs.jpg"></marquee>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float:left; width:50px">
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:50px" >
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
<img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Jaffa.png">
</div>
<p style="text-align: center; position: absolute; z-index: -1; width: 100%">
<marquee><img src="http://benjiworld.ueuo.com/Hobnobs.jpg"></marquee>
</p>
```